# Mapbox js map without tiles

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox

I want to display a choropleth using the mapbox framework. I have a working example already that uses the mapbox.light style. What I want to achieve is to have a blank map that only displays the polygons. In short, I want to disable mapbox tiling. Is this possible? I have been trying to achieve the same thing using d3 without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide layers:

**mapbox**:

```
map.eachLayer( function(t,e) {
  if (t.setOpacity) t.setOpacity(0.5);
});
```

**mapbox gl js**:

```
map
  .getStyle() 
  .layers
  .forEach(function(layer) {  
    map.setLayoutProperty(layer.id, 'visibility', 'none');
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need.